# Using class methods and properties outside wordpress (functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I create a class within my `functions.php` that contains some properties and methods about Wordpress post formats. now my class contain the some code about Quote post format. but I don't know how I can use the `YPE_QPA()` method and `icon` property within other Wordpress files. for example how I can use this method and property within `index.php`?

```
class YPE_post_formats {

public $icon = '<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>';

public function YPE_QPA() {
    $quote_post = get_the_content();
    $quote_post = wpautop($quote_post);

    $quote_text = substr($quote_post, 0 , strpos($quote_post, '</p>') + 4);
    $quote_text = strip_tags($quote_text, '<a><strong><em><i>');

}
}

$YPE_PFormats = new YPE_post_formats();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any script that includes your `functions.php` script should be able to create an instance of your `YPE_QPA` class.

```
include_once('path/to/functions.php');

$YPE_PFormats = new YPE_post_formats();
$YPE_PFormats->YPE_QPA();
```

Comment: thank you very much because every wordpress files can access every functions within `functions.php` don't requires `include_once('path/to/functions.php'); but must create instance of class outside of `functions.php` or use `global` keyword to access class instance
`